# Google Sheets Read Only on Android

Tags: google-sheets

I created a spreadsheet in Google Sheets. I shared the link with two users. They can click on the link in the e-mail and can edit the spreadsheet with no issue. However, one of the users created a shortcut on their Android Phone (LG G7 ThinQ). When she opens the spreadsheet from her phone it is Read Only and cannot perform any edits. She is using the same gmail account on her phone that I sent the link too. Any ideas what might be causing this?